# Can I reference a Shared Project from a .NET Standard Library?

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, .net-standard

It looks like .NET Standard Libraries cannot add a Shared Project as a reference.

I created a .NET Standard 1.4 Library and am trying to reference an existing Shared Library from the the .NET Standard Library.

But, the code in the Shared Libary doesn't inherit any of the `System` libraries from my .NET Standard Libary.

For example, the below code produces this error message:

> The type of namespace name 'System' could not be found...

```cs
using System;

namespace SharedProject1
{
    ...
}
```

I am currently running Visual Studio 15.3.0 Preview 2.1

[image]

Comment: So that library don't use `string`s, `int`s, etc?

Comment: I just added a newly created shared lib into a netstandard 1.4 library. VS 15.2 stable compiles it without any problem.

Comment: Are you referencing the same frameworks in your referenced project *and* your UI test project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the preview of Visual Studio 15.3 and has been fixed as of 15.3 Preview 6.

This bug also exists in Visual Studio for Mac, and has been fixed as of version 7.1 Build 1294.